# SharePoint 2010 - login without using AD accounts?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, content-management-system, authentication, sharepoint-2010

If I create a public facing internet site using SharePoint as the backend, how do I change the login process so that it doesn't use AD / Local Windows accounts?

I want to have a registration process for logins which the admin will approve before giving out access to users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use forms based authentication with users stored in SQL Server tables. See: http://blog.summitcloud.com/2009/11/forms-based-authentication-sharepoint-2010-fb/

Answer (score 2):

The first must-read is this : [Plan authentication methods](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx)

However, why don't you use an anonymous enabled page with a "request access" form ? The form can then start a workflow which one actual "CreateLogin" activity. This activity then creates the login on AD, SQL or any authentication provider. It can also push the request to any external login creation process.

HTH